# Употребление слова "гражданин"

Tags: стилистика

Грамотно ли говорить "гражданин" о жителе страны? Ведь слово происходит от "город", значит, гражданин — это житель города, а не страны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно, слово **ГРАЖДАНИН** происходит от слова *город*. Значение "житель города, горожанин" - одно из значений современного многозначного слова ГРАЖДАНИН, причем устаревшее. Главным (первым) значением является все-таки "лицо, принадлежащее к постоянному населению данного государства, пользующееся всеми правами, обеспеченными законами этого государства, и исполняющее все установленные законами обязанности; подданный какого-л. государства".

Answer (score 0):

О жителе страны - нормально. 
Вопрос, какой страны...

Я, конечно, понимаю, что определение хорошее, обтекаемое и предельно либеральное. Но никой критики не выдерживает с точки зрения международного права... 
Гражданство - это не отношения человека и государства, это отношения между государствами по поводу этого человека.
Гражданин - лицо на которое государство распространяет свою власть в полном объеме, без необходимоти вступать в юридические отношения с другим государством. Как-то так... С массой оговорок, конечно, но суть, надеюсь, понятна.

Вопрос на засыпку. Чем гражданин отличается от подданного? И можно ли быть одновременно и тем и другим (а отношении одного государства?)

Answer (score 0):

Я полностью согласна с behemothus, что гражданин - это житель или "подданный" какой-либо страны. Но хотелось бы добавить, что в Словаре русских синонимов даётся следующий ряд: горожанин — городской житель, мещанин, обыватель, ГРАЖДАНИН, городочинец, градожитель...
Городские обыватели — в законодательстве Российской империи -  это сословие городских жителей (известное также как городское состояние и под именем ГРАЖДАН).
Когда Павел I запретил слово «гражданин«, он заменил его словом "обыватель". Вспомним пушкинское "Я просто русский мещанин..." Но уже в 19 веке 
мещане, обыватели начали противопоставляться революционно настроенной части населения - гражданам.
Таким образом, я думаю, что изначально "гражданин" означало просто житель города, горожанин. Сегодня "гражданин" - это подданный страны и, по-видимому, патриот.